# Threading lock in WinForms

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winforms, deadlock

I have a class that generates images in a thread and invokes an event on every frame. A `Form` subscribes to this event and displays the image in a `PictureBox` using `Invoke`.

If the image generation process is allowed to finish, all is good. However, if the `Form` is closed while the thread is running, the `Form` tries to stop the thread but ends up in some sort of a deadlock.

When I try to use the threaded class in without a `Form` or in a `Console` app, start the process, wait for a second, then `Cancel` it, everything works fine.

The question is, something must be wrong with either the `Form_Closing` method of the `Form` or the `Stop` method of the threaded class.

I have kept the code to a minimum and it can be pasted into LinqPad, etc.

An auxiliary question: Should the `Process` method invoke the `Stop` method to clean up?

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace VideoMask.WinFormsAppApp
{
    internal static class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        private static void Main ()
        {
            Program.TestWithoutForm(); // Runs fine.
            Program.TestWithForm(); // Deadlocks.
        }

        private static void TestWithForm ()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

            Application.Run(new FormMain());
        }

        private static void TestWithoutForm ()
        {
            new TestWithoutForm().Run();
        }
    }

    public class TestWithoutForm
    {
        private VideoProcessor VideoProcessor = new VideoProcessor();

        public TestWithoutForm ()
        {
            this.VideoProcessor.SourceFrameRead += this.VideoProcessor_SourceFrameRead;
        }

        public void Run ()
        {
            this.VideoProcessor.Start();
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            this.VideoProcessor.Stop();

            MessageBox.Show("Done");
        }

        private void VideoProcessor_SourceFrameRead (object sender, VideoProcessorEventArgs e)
        {
            var filename = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), "Sample.png");

            e.Bitmap.Save(filename, ImageFormat.Png);
        }
    }


    public class FormMain: Form
    {
        private PictureBox PictureBox = new PictureBox();
        private VideoProcessor VideoProcessor = new VideoProcessor();

        public FormMain ()
        {
            this.Controls.Add(this.PictureBox);
            this.PictureBox.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

            this.Shown += this.FormMain_Shown;
            this.FormClosing += this.FormMain_FormClosing;

            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
        }

        private void FormMain_Shown (object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.VideoProcessor.SourceFrameRead += this.VideoProcessor_SourceFrameRead;
            this.VideoProcessor.Start();
        }

        private void FormMain_FormClosing (object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            this.VideoProcessor.Stop();
            this.VideoProcessor.Dispose();
            this.VideoProcessor = null;
        }

        private void VideoProcessor_SourceFrameRead (object sender, VideoProcessorEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Invoke
            (
                new Action
                (
                    () =>
                    {
                        using (var bitmap = this.PictureBox.Image)
                        {
                            this.PictureBox.Image = new Bitmap(e.Bitmap);
                        }
                    }
                )
            );
        }
    }

    public sealed class VideoProcessor: IDisposable
    {
        public event EventHandler<ErrorEventArgs> ConversionError = null;
        public event EventHandler<VideoProcessorEventArgs> SourceFrameRead = null;

        private Font Font = null;
        private Bitmap Bitmap = null;
        private Thread Thread = null;
        private Graphics Graphics = null;
        private readonly object SyncRoot = new object();
        private CancellationTokenSource CancellationTokenSource = null;

        public VideoProcessor ()
        {
            this.Bitmap = new Bitmap(800, 600, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
            this.Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(this.Bitmap);
            this.Font = new Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif, 48, GraphicsUnit.Point);
        }

        public bool IsRunning { get; private set; }

        public void Start ()
        {
            lock (this.SyncRoot)
            {
                if (this.IsRunning) { throw (new Exception("A video conversion process is already running.")); }

                this.Stop();
                this.CancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
                this.Thread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(this.Process));
                this.Thread.Start(this.CancellationTokenSource);
            }
        }

        public void Stop ()
        {
            lock (this.SyncRoot)
            {
                if (!this.IsRunning) { return; }

                this.CancellationTokenSource?.Cancel();

                this.Thread.Join();

                this.Thread = null;
                this.CancellationTokenSource?.Dispose();
                this.CancellationTokenSource = null;
            }
        }

        private void Process (object cancellationTokenSource)
        {
            var source = (CancellationTokenSource) cancellationTokenSource ?? throw (new ArgumentNullException(nameof(cancellationTokenSource)));

            lock (this.SyncRoot) { if (this.IsRunning) { throw (new Exception("A conversion process is already running.")); } }

            this.IsRunning = true;

            for (var i = 1; i <= int.MaxValue; i++)
            {
                if (source.IsCancellationRequested) { break; }

                this.Graphics.Clear(Color.White);
                this.Graphics.DrawString(i.ToString(), this.Font, Brushes.Black, 10, 10);
                this.SourceFrameRead?.Invoke(this, new VideoProcessorEventArgs(this.Bitmap));

                Thread.Sleep(33);
            }

            this.IsRunning = false;
        }

        public void Dispose () => this.Stop();
    }

    public class VideoProcessorEventArgs: EventArgs
    {
        public Bitmap Bitmap { get; private set; }
        public VideoProcessorEventArgs (Bitmap bitmap) { this.Bitmap = bitmap; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you run a Task instead of a thread, so the CancellationToken can throw as it is supposed to and you also remove `this.Thread.Join();` (which, mixed with `Invoke()` is kind of looking for this to happen)? Btw, you're calling both `Stop()` and `Dispose()`, which are doing the same thing and you're not disposing the Images you set to the PictureBox Control (have just `this.PictureBox.Image?.Dispose(); this.PictureBox.Image = e.Bitmap;`).

Comment: @Jimi, I cannot use a `Task` in this case, hence the question about a `Thread`. The images are being disposed for the `PictureBox` due to the `using`. I still think that something must be wrong with either the Form_Closing method of the Form or the Stop method of the threaded class. Lastly, calling both `Close` and `Dispose` in sequence should not have any consequences.

Comment: Well, if you cannot... (I won't ask you why :). Change `Invoke()` to `BeginInvoke()` (in `VideoProcessor_SourceFrameRead`, of course). The double call to `Stop()` may not be an issue, but it's not clear what's for (maybe this class is a work in progress?). I'll know when I can test it. Use this `this.PictureBox.Image?.Dispose(); this.PictureBox.Image = e.Bitmap;` to dispose of the previous Bitmap.

Comment: I've tested it and of course `BeginInvoke()` solves the most direct issue, the deadlock is gone (you're not tripping on `Invoke()` + `thread.Join()` anymore - maybe it's there because this class is actually meant to be used concurrently?). -- I suggested to add `this.PictureBox.Image?.Dispose();` so you could make it fail. You're drawing on the same Bitmap all the time: if this is really what you want to do, then you don't need to dispose of that Bitmap on the Form side, but on the `VideoProcessor` side. If you generate new Bitmaps, dispose of them like that.

Comment: Btw, if you actually want/have to draw on the same Bitmap (i.e., this class is not a proxy that's using a Video input from somewhere else), you could expose your Bitmap as a read-only public property, assign the Bitmap to the PictureBox after the class initialization and, in the `VideoProcessor_SourceFrameRead` handler, have just `this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => PictureBox.Refresh()));` or `this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => PictureBox.Invalidate()));` (not the same thing).

Comment: E.g., if you remove `Thread.Sleep(33);` and call `picFrame.Refresh();` you have the Form stuck again, but it's not a deadlock this time. With `Invalidate()`, you can go down to `Thread.Sleep(1);` (it may not be beautiful), but you can move the Form around etc.

Comment: With *[...] you don't need to dispose of that Bitmap on the Form side, but on the VideoProcessor side* I mean when you dispose of that class object.

Comment: Thanks @Jimi, for all the comments. You should post an answer since `BeginInvoke` does indeed solve the problem. Lastly, and since you mentioned it multiple times, take a look at the `using` statement in the `VideoProcessor_SourceFrameRead ` method. The is how the image gets disposed on the `Form` side. I could have called `Dispose` on it just as well.

Comment: Additionally, although the code posted was adapted for this question, the reason for re-using the same bitmap is performance. This is for a video-editing/transcoding app and that bitmap should not be disposed of at all during the conversion process.

Comment: Yes, that makes perfectly sense and that's what I supposed you actually wanted to do, the note about using `this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => PictureBox.Invalidate()));` was about that. In case you need to dispose of the Bitmap (I know, I'm repeating myself), use this pattern: `this.PictureBox.Image?.Dispose(); this.PictureBox.Image = e.Bitmap;`: with a time-sensitive operation going on, you may want to avoid the `try/finally` block built around `using`. The other pattern does the same thing without unneeded overhead. -- I'll post some notes on as soon as I have a *real* keyboard available.